# Cannot assign dot to variable in Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, centos6.5

I run this command both by typing in Terminal and by executing file on CentOS 6.5 64 bits.

```
let t='.'; echo $t;
```

Can't believe that it yields such a wierd error:

```
-bash: let: t=.: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".")
```

As far as I know, single-quoted strings should not be parsed. In fact, in the first place, what I wanted to do is:

```
let $target_path='./files/mp4';
```

Can anyone please explain this behavior and guide me to stop this wierd act?

Comment: Just use `target_path='./files/mp4'`. Variables in bash are set like `var="value"`, not `$var="value"`. To use then later on, you do use the dollar: `echo "$var"`. Also, there is no need to use `;` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you want to evaluate the variable value as an arithmetical expression, you need to assign the [variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) value like this:

```
t='.'
```

`let` is for calculation of arithmetical expressions and `.` or `./files/mp4` produces a syntax error in that arithmetical expression. Check `help let`.

---

Here comes an example how `let` can be used:

```
a="10*2"
echo "$a" # Prints: 10*2

let a="10*2"
echo "$a" # Prints: 20
```

---

If you followed the discussion below you may have noticed that even for mathematical expressions `let` isn't the best choice. This is because you can use `ARITHMETIC EXPANSION` in that case which is defined by POSIX in opposite to `let`. Using `ARITHMETIC EXPANSION` the above example would look like this:

```
a=$((10*2))
echo "$a" # Prints: 20
```

Check this articles for further information:

- [let](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let)
- [arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

Comment: Also, note that `let` is generally necessary, as you can also write `a=$((10 * 2))` (which has the benefit of being part of the POSIX standard).

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure if `let` and arithmetic expansion can do the *same*. I guess not. The documentation doesn't explicitly state that. Also OP is searching for a string assignement. That's why I don't wanted to point to alternatives to `let`, i justed wanted to show the basic difference between a `let` assignment and a string assignment.

Comment: (I do have a typo, should be "`let` is generally unnecessary"). At the very least, `let` is superseded by the `(( ... ))` command. According to the man page, `let "expression"` is identical to `((expression))`.

Comment: (And +1, since at least in this case regular assignment is what you need. Just wanted to point out the `let` itself is probably never needed, and one would do just fine not knowing it existed to avoid this type of error.)

Comment: `According to the man page, let "expression" is identical to ((expression))` This was what I needed. I just wasn't exactly sure. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `let` here is not right.
You can do like this:

```
AMD$ t='.'
AMD$ echo $t
.

AMD$ t='./files/mp4'
AMD$ echo $t
./files/mp4
```